# Set custom commands

Tags: macros

Very often I have to write `\text{im}(f)`, to denote the image of f, if I try to write, `\im f`, then it generates the Imaginary notation which I do not want, if I write `im f` then it looks awful. Is there a way to tell my editor to recognize `\im` to generate `\text{im}` so that I do not need to write it every time?

Comment: Please do not *ever* use `\text` to mark a mathematical construction! It is for textual comments only! This is a very common mistake. Why so bad? `\textit{$\text{im}(f)$}` gives an italic `im` which is not correct. Ians solution is the proper one.

Comment: @daleif In all my time using Latex, I never had a problem that you describe. Perhaps, I am lucky, but it could just be a theoretical problem?

Comment: You have just been lucky. Considering that most people use italics for their theorem statements, thus `\text` switch to italics inside theorems and definitions). `\text{Im}` does  not get the proper spacing either (Ians solution does). I see this error a lot among students. The two most common mistakes is (1) the one you do here, and (2) `X_{\text{max}}` which suffer from the same problem. Here `\mathrm` or even `\textup` is more correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not create a new macro? You could do

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

and then

```
\DeclareMathOperator\Img{Im}
```

after which `\Img` creates the notation that you want, with correct spacing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
\newcommand{\im}{\operatorname{Im}}
```

or go with `amsmath` and use @Ian_Thompson's solution, which is my favorite.
These two solutions give a proper mathematical spacing but select a font automatically.

If math spacing is not required, use

```
\newcommand{\im}{\mathrm{Im}}
```

To get math spacing with font selection use

```
\newcommand{\im}{\mathop{\mathrm{im}}}
```